# Kubernetes CronJob, don't queue up missed jobs

Tags: cron, kubernetes

I've read [these docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) over multiple times but still don't think I understand what `startingDeadlineSeconds` does.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to avoid rescheduling a job if a current one is running (with `CronJob`) and instead just let the *next* scheduled job pick up where it left off.

I have some extremely erratic job completion times (a separate problem I need to solve). It may take 1 hour or up to 24. So sometimes, if a Job takes a whole day to complete, but I've scheduled it to run every 12 hours, I get a queue of another job that immediately starts when the last one is complete.

I'd really just like it to *never* queue up a job and only create new jobs on the *next* scheduled time.

Here's a sample of the config

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: my-job
spec:
  schedule: "0 */2 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 1
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: my-job
            image: my-image
            command: ["do_something"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Note that `do_somethign` could take 1 hour, or it could take 4 hours. What I'd like, is when it takes 4 hours, to *not* have queued up the 2nd job that would have normally run if it had taken less.

Is this possible with Kubernetes CronJob?

Comment: The docs make it sound like `concurrencyPolicy` controls this behavior. But I think you should post the `CronJob` so we can see all the settings being used.

Comment: `concurrencyPolicy` only affects whether 2 jobs can run at the same time. Ya good call, I'll post the cronjob sample

Comment: If I understand correctly, the `concurrencyPolicy` will prevent the job from running in parallel _but_ queues it up to run immediately after the current one is finished, which is what you are trying to prevent (you would rather it skipped)?

Comment: correct, it queues up a 2nd job, and I'd rather have it skipped

Comment: I have made some research and your `CronJob` seems to be correct. Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52691631/kubernetes-cronjob-skip-job-if-previous-is-still-running-and-wait-for-the-next) also proves that it should be working as you want it to. Try without `successfulJobsHistoryLimit` and `backoffLimit`. Make it look like more the example below:

Comment: `apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: your-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/40 8-18 * * 1-6"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: your-periodic-job
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: your_container
            image: your_image
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          restartPolicy: OnFailure`

Adjust the data of course and let me know if that helped please.